# Problem with access to mounted drive

Tags: mount, chmod

I can not make my newly mounted hdd work properly. First and foremost, I can not access it to read and write any file or folder even after changing the privileges to +775 and even +777 (though I can see the files and directories all right). This is the biggest problem.

Secondly and this is a more theoretical question, when I am trying to unmount it, the system reports that the drive is busy. fuser command shows the drive is busy by a process with c post-fix (2177c). What does this "c" means?
I did manage to umnount the hdd using lazy umount thought.

I understand that I am doing smth wrong here. Could you please indicate what my mistake is - I can not figure what can be wrong here using the leads available from google search.

I put in the list of commands I used to mount the hdd and chmod the permissions. Just for a reference - I am doing all that using ssh.

```
xxx@123 ~ $ mkdir hddmount
xxx@123 ~ $ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home/xxx/hddmount
xxx@123 ~ $ sudo chmod 775 /home/xxx/hddmount
xxx@123 ~ $ pwd
/home/xxx
xxx@123 ~ $ ls
Desktop  hddmount  Downloads
xxx@123 ~ $ cd hddmount
pi@123 ~/hddmount $ ls
Autorun.inf  Seagate  SeagateExpansion.ico  Setup.exe  Warranty.pdf

xxx@123 ~/hddmount $ mkdir Test
mkdir: cannot create directory `Test': Permission denied
xxx@123 ~/hddmount $
```

mkdir in sudo mode results in:

```
xxx@123 ~/hddmount $ sudo mkdir Test
mkdir: cannot create directory `Test': Operation not permitted
```

Why does sudo can not override permissions - this is the third question is am struggling with.

---

Output of df -h:

```
/dev/sda0       141G   46G   89G  34% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.5G  4.0K  1.5G   1% /dev
tmpfs           297M  1.5M  295M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.5G  560K  1.5G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   12K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1       1.9T  150M  1.9T   1% /home/xxx/hddmount
```

Comment: Do you have an entry in /etc/fstab for this disk?  Is it mounted in a readonly fashion?

Comment: I have not touched /etc/fstab yet (it would my next step) - as I understand for read/write access chmod should do the job. Or am I wrong here? And I can not even read - that's the biggest puzzle for me - only the names of the files are visible....

Comment: It's probably a combination of the two.  This is a second disk?  Can you enter the command `df -h` and append the output to your question

Comment: If it's an NTFS partition, `chmod` won't help you. You have to set permissions using mount options (`uid=XXXX,gid=YYYY`) Presumably you have just execute permission on the folder, no more. What is the output of `ls -l /home/xxx/`? And the output of `mount | grep sda1`?

Comment: Right! 99% that is my error! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a 2TB disk (Seagate), so it needed to be mounted with -y ntfs-3g option (presuming ntfs-3g is installed).
/etc/fstab should also hold ntfs-3g option, otherwise the problem persists. 
just adding uid, gid, fmask and dmask options to **mount** command without the proper file system indication did not work as well in my case.

Many thanks to all!